# TypeUndefined Error in JavaScript/Node.JS App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently learning on my own JavaScript/Node.JS and i am following a tutorial on building a simple RESTful app with Node.JS and MongoDB. While following the tutorial when building the /userlist route in my users.js file I attempt to retrieve the users from the database.

I run into the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
>       at /Users/bogdan/Sites/noderest/routes/users.js:8:7

I have pasted below my app.js and users.js for reference, perhaps I am missing something.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;

    db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
       res.json(items);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My app.js is below.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// this is the database code. it connects to our local database and uses the db variable to store a reference to 
// our connection

var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/noderest", {native_parser: true});

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// define the database as accessible to the node router.
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error, it's saying db is undefined and therefore can't read "collection"..

So where is req declared?

      `var db = req.db;`

Remembering that req passed into the parameters is the request from the user and so shouldn't /wont have a db object in it.

Comment: add 'app.use(function(req, res, next){req.db = db;next();});' before 'app.use('/', routes);app.use('/users', users);' and check. You need to make your db accessible to the routes.

Comment: Sourabh, thanks that helped, I must have missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use another pattern:

Rewrite your routing module:

```
module.exports = function(db) {

    return {

         yourRoute: function(req, res) {

                 db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                        res.json(items);
                  });
            } 
     }

}
```

and than just pass the db module in your app.js

```
var db = new yourDb();
var myRoute = require(./myRoute)(db);
```

and than pass the route to your module:

```
app.get('/', myRoute.yourRoute);
```

Comment: Solick: I like the way you rewrote the module, I hope you do not mind if i borrow this style?

Comment: Of course the general pattern is not my idea, i also was looking for a good solution to have eg only one db object in my whole app and pass it to the router modules.

Answer (score 0):

in users.js you are doing wrong at

```
var db=req.db
```

actually you have to install and run the mongodb in your system. For this follow this documentaion 
*http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/*

then install **mongojs** module

reference to install *https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb*

after running mongodb add following code to users.js

```
mongojs = require("mongojs");
var uri = "mongodb://demo_user:demo_password@ds027769.mongolab.com:27769/demo_database",
db = mongojs.connect(uri, ["collection"]);
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {   
   db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.json(items);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Rams, I already found my answer. It works just fine now. I managed to fix it using the users on top!